# How to validate condition in render return using react native?

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native

In my scenario, I am trying to create a `validation` logic within render return. I have `asycstorage` value I am getting value and validate by using below code

```
render() {
    const value = AsyncStorage.getItem(‘username’);
  return (
{value !== null &&
        (<View
        ……………..
         </View> )}
)}
```

Above code not validating also based on validation result it is not rendering. If value not equal to null mean, I need to render view. How to achieve this?

Comment: AsyncStorage returns a promise. So you can't handle it like above.

Comment: @SDushan Please suggest some other good method.

Comment: Don't call it inside render function, call it inside ```componentDidMount``` or ```useEffect```.

Answer (score 0):

As said, AsyncStorage returns a promise. A way to do what you want is to use state to know when the promise has been completed. However you have to call your AsyncStorage function before render.

```
didComponentMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(‘username’).then((res)=>{this.setState({gotUsername: true}); value = res;});
}

render(){
    if(!this.state.gotUsername) {
        return value !== null &&
         (<View

         </View> )
    }
}
```

Comment: ```render``` should always remain pure. It's a very bad practice to call ```setState``` inside ```render```.

Comment: @Terry I am storing async values in same didcomponentmount. Store and get both I am doing in same place

Comment: @questanswer I'm not sure that I get what you mean then?

Comment: @Terry storing AsyncStorage.setItem('username', 'jack'); also I am doing into same didComponentMount() and as per your answer get item also I need to do same place. is it a good way?

Comment: @questanswer so you are setting the username in  didComponentMount() if I understand well? Why do you need to retrieve it then if you already know the username? Maybe you could update your code with more details about your component logic.